# Toggle hide/show not working on childs div

Tags: javascript, html, tabletop.js

I have a script that gets data from a Google Sheet and displays it as a webpage - using JS and Tabletop.js.

There are multiple entries in the Sheet thus multiple entries in the webpage. To organise the Data I have a hide/show button. When the button is clicked on the first entry it works. However when the any of the other buttons are clicked it hides or shows the first entries data, not its own!

How do I hide/show each individual entries data? Below is the code I am working with!

I am new to JavaScript - Thanks in advance!

P.S - I struggled writing the Title to the questions!

```
    <link href="../common/cats-copy.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  </head>

    <style>
    #add-info {
    display: none
    }
    </style>

  <body>

      <div class="container">
    <h1>Resturants</h1>

    <div id="content"></div>

    <script id="cat-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

      <div class="entry">
        <h5>{{establishment_name}}</h5>
        <h6>Area: {{area}}</h6>
        <h6>Cuisine: {{cuisine}}</h6>
          <button id="btn" class="button-primary" onclick="myFunction()">Hide</button>
        <div id="add-info">
        <h6>Address: {{address}}</h6>
        <h6>Google Maps: {{google_maps_location}}</h6>
        <h6>Opening Times: {{opening_times}}</h6>
        <h6>Rating: {{rating}}</h6>
        <h6>Added By: {{added_by}}</h6>
        <h6>Date Added: {{date_added}}</h6>
        </div>
      </div>

    </script>

      </div>

    <!-- Don't need jQuery for Tabletop, but using it for this example -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="handlebars.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../src/tabletop.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
      var public_spreadsheet_url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h5zYzEcBIA5zUDc9j4BTs8AcJj-21-ykzq6238CnkWc/edit?usp=sharing';

      $(document).ready( function() {
        Tabletop.init( { key: public_spreadsheet_url,
                         callback: showInfo,
                         parseNumbers: true } );
      });

      function showInfo(data, tabletop) {
        var source   = $("#cat-template").html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

        $.each( tabletop.sheets("food").all(), function(i, food) {
          var html = template(food);
          $("#content").append(html);
        });
      }

    </script>

      <script>

                function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("add-info");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
      </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Shouldnt the `<style></style>` tags be in `<head>` tag?
Also better to have a external CSS file.
I dont know if this is how it must be in "tabletop.js"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are all the entries on your page filled from the given template, meaning they are `div`s with the class `entry`? If so, I think your issue is the following: Your `entry` `div` has a child `div` with the `id="add-info"`. And when you click the button, your handler function (`myFunction()`) tries to get a reference to that `div` via `document.getElementById("add-info");` Now, if you have multiple such entries on a page, you will have multiple `div`s with `id="add-info"`. But *the `id` attribute of an element must be unique in your whole document*. See the description of [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) or that of [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

So the root cause of your problem is that the same `id` is used multiple times in the document when it shouldn't be. You get the behavior you're seeing because `getElementById()` just happens to be returning a reference to the first element it finds on the page, regardless of which button you click. But I believe you're in undefined behavior territory at that point.

One way to solve the problem is to somehow give `myFunction()` information about which button was clicked, while making each `div` you'd like to manipulate unique so they can be found easier. For instance, you can use the order of the restaurant on your page as its "index", and use that as the `id` of the `div` you'd like to hide/show. And you can also pass this index as an argument when you call your click handler:

```
...
<button id="btn" class="button-primary" onclick="myFunction('{{index}}')">Hide</button>
<div id="{{index}}">
<!-- The rest of the code here... -->
...
```

... add the index into your template context, so `Handlebars` can fill in the `{{index}}` placeholder:

```
...
$.each( tabletop.sheets("food").all(), function(i, food) {
  food.index = i    // Give your context its 'index'
  var html = template(food);
  $("#content").append(html);
});
...
```

... and then alter your function slightly to use the given argument instead of always looking for the `div` with `id="add-info"`:

```
function myFunction(indexToToggle) {
  var x = document.getElementById(indexToToggle);
  // rest of the code is same
```

With this approach, I expect your DOM to end up with `div`s that have `id`s that are just numbers (`"3"`, `"4"`, etc.) and your click handler should get called with those as arguments as well.

Also note that your `<button>` element has `id="btn"`. If you repeat that template on your page, you will have multiple `<button>`s with the same `id`. If you start trying to get references to your `button`s via `id` you will have similar issues with them too since the `id`s won't be unique.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however I still can't seam to this to work! Is it possible to add $(this).?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly isn't working? I also don't quite follow what you mean by "Is it possible to add $(this).?". Add it to what context? The [`this` binding in your event handler could get you a reference to the element that triggered the event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers#Event_handler's_parameters_this_binding_and_the_return_value), but that would give you your `<button>` and you'd still have to figure out how to get at the `div` you'd like to hide from there.

Comment: So I managed to rewrite the script to get it to do the current thing: <script type="text/javascript">
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
    
    var x = '.' + clicked_id;
    
    
    $(x).slideToggle("500", function() { 
    if ($(x).css('display') == 'none') {
        console.log(clicked_id)
              document.getElementById(clicked_id).innerHTML = "Show";
         }
         else {
              document.getElementById(clicked_id).innerHTML = "Hide";
         }
       
});
        
}

    
    


</script>

Comment: However I now I have an issue where the some {{establishment_name}}'s are not a single word, they are multiple. Do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: Yeah, using the establishment name was an example of the idea to use something that's unique. But you can't have spaces in the `id` attribute. A better approach would be to not deal with names as `id`s and use something like an index. I'll modify my answer since it'll be too much to point out in comments here.

Comment: Great - Works perfectly!